# Change startup screen

Tags: 8.1, lumia, display

My Lumia 1020 came locked to my provider's carrier (O2 UK), as part of the customisation the startup screen shows their animated logo for a few seconds.

I've had the phone unlocked and moved to another carrier but this logo remains. Is it something I can customise or is it baked into the phone somehow?

Comment: Does the phone have the carrier's logo on it? I'm pretty sure there's no way to get rid of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this without modifying the ROM, without getting a custom ROM to be installed and, essentially, without voiding your warranty. The same holds even for the more open system Android!